# Positioning ggplots in patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I have graph consisting of several `ggplots` combined using `patchwork`. I have made a `ggplot` only consisting of the y-axis. I'm now struggling to move this y-axis ggplot closer to the ggplots. Any ideas?

[image]

Here's the pacthwork code:

```
y_axis + decreasers_p+late_bloomers_p + o2_lovers_p + solo_riders_p + plot_layout(widths = c(1, 10), 
                                                                        guides = "collect",
                                                                        design = 
                                                                        "12
                                                                         13
                                                                         14
                                                                         15")
```

And here's some of the ggplot code:

```
solo_riders_p <- ggplot(solo_riders, aes(x=days_incubated, y=emission))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=compound, size=compound, fill=compound)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 25))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(2.8, 2.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "grey"))+
  labs(fill = "Compound", shape = "Compound", size = "Compound", 
       x = "Incubation time (days)", 
       y = "BVOC emission (nmol g-1 loi soil h-1)", 
       title = "solo_riders") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(jar), scales = "free_y")

y_axis <- ggplot(data.frame(l = decreasers_p$labels$y, x = 1, y = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = l), angle = 90) + 
  theme_void() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

Comment: Does decreasing the first `width` to 0.5 not help?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using ggplot2's theme system to generate an appropriate y-axis title as a grob, which you can then patchwork onto the others. If you're using a custom theme that is not global, replace the `theme_get()` by your theme.

Shown with dummy plots as I don't have the data to reproduce your exact usecase.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

plt <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "")

yaxis <- calc_element("axis.title.y.left", theme_get())
yaxis <- element_grob(yaxis, label = "mpg")

plt + plt + yaxis +
  plot_layout(
    design = c("31\n32"),
    widths = c(0.01, 1)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>